# How do I simply set the user's timezone in CodeIgniter for all SELECTs

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, timezone

I am running MYSQL in UTC by default. I want all selects to be done in the user's local time, but all inserts and updates to be in UTC. How do I do this? I know of the CONVERT_TZ function, but I don't want to have to wrap every select if at all possible. Is there a way to set the users timezone ONCE after they log in? I am using CodeIgniter and non-persistent so I assume I have to set it every time I connect?

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Your index.php file in the root Folder use:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
```

And Set your time zone here.
All codeigniter Requests pass through this file. So it will set Your time Zone

Comment: But that gets called before any user has logged in and each user has a different timezone.

Comment: No it gets called before loading every page.. so this works

Comment: What I mean is, the user has not logged in yet so I don't know what timezone to set for him.